# Is this the right way to pass an array back from the function to main

Tags: c, arrays, function

The program is running without errors, but it stops after it runs this function since it seems that the array is not being passed back. Is this the right way to pass the array back to the function? I've included only the essential code below. Please could you point out where I might be wrong.

```
int matchedNumbersfunc(int lotoNumbers[],int ticketNumbers[], int *numbersRight);

int main()
{
    int lotoNumbers[7];
    int ticketNumbers[7];
    int matchedNumbers[7];
    int numbersRight = 0;

    matchedNumbers[7] = matchedNumbersfunc(ticketNumbers, lotoNumbers, &numbersRight);

    return 0;
}

int matchedNumbersfunc(int lotoNumbers[],int ticketNumbers[], int *numbersRight)
{
    int matchedNumbers[7];
    int i, k ,j;
    *numbersRight = 0; 

    for(k=0;k<7;k++)
    {
        matchedNumbers[k] = 0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            if(ticketNumbers[i] == lotoNumbers[j])
            {
                matchedNumbers[i] = ticketNumbers[i];
            }
        }
        if(matchedNumbers[i] != 0)
        {
            printf("You have a winning number: %d\n", matchedNumbers[i]);
            *numbersRight = *numbersRight + 1;

            if(matchedNumbers[6] != 0)
            {
                *numbersRight = *numbersRight - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return matchedNumbers[7];
}
```

Comment: At first glance, it's wrong. For an array of 7 elements, only index `0` to `6` are valid.

Comment: Array's index goes from from 0 to 6. So `matchedNumbers[7]` is outside the bounds of the array. You are not really returning an array but a value of the array and that too outside the bounds, resulting in *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: you can't return arrays, what you can do is return a pointer to the first element

Comment: And that pointer, shouldn't point to something of auto storage class.  You're far better in passing in the address of the array, from main, then letting the function set the values in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are returning a single value rather than an array. And as it happens, you are returning a value off the end of the array, and assigning to a value off the end of another array. Your arrays have `7` elements, indexed `0` to `6`.

What you need to do is pass an array to the function and let the function populate it. A simple example:

```
void foo(int array[], size_t count)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        array[i] = i;
}
```

Which you would call like this:

```
int myArray[7];
foo(myArray, 7);
```

Comment: How would the part before foo(myArray, 7); look like? Like what would it be equal too. Another array?

Comment: It is exactly as written. The function is `void`. There is no return value from the function. When `foo` returns, the caller's array, `myArray` has been populated.

Comment: Is there a way to do it the way i did? Cause my assignment wants the two arrays to be passed to the function ( ticketNumbers and lotoNumbers) and 1 function to be returned which is (matchedNumbers).

Comment: No. You have to do it the way I demonstrate. Or I suppose you could malloc memory in the function and return that. But I see no reason why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to allocate a new array dynamically in your function and return a pointer to that array with this prototype:

```
int* matchedNumbersfunc(int lotoNumbers[],int ticketNumbers[], int *numbersRight);
```

Your revised function would start like this:

```
int* matchedNumbers;
int i, k ,j;
*numbersRight = 0; 


matchedNumbers = (int*) calloc (7, sizeof(int));
if (matchedNumbers==NULL) 
     return NULL; 
for(k=0;k<7;k++)
...
return (matchedNumbers);
```

In the main() you do not need to allocate the table, but just a pointer:

```
...
int *matchedNumbers;
...

matchedNumbers = matchedNumbersfunc(...);
if (matchedNumbers==NULL) 
    { /* not enough memory - some kind of error processing */ }

free (matchedNumbers);   // once you don't need the result anymore

return 0;
```

For your simple programme dynamic allocation could be overkill. But for more complex processing, this approach could be useful as well.